# how to open image into external app from flutterapp

Tags: flutter

```
InkResponse(
              child: Image.file(
                File(person.photoUri),
                width: 200,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 200,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                //open this image into Other Image viewer apps
              },
            ),
```

I have file stored in external storage. The url of this file is stored in person.photoUri variable how can I open External app to show this image.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) plugin or [intent](https://pub.dev/packages/intent) plugin. It helps you to view multimedia.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) plugin.

maybe you can add something like this in your `onTap`:

```dart
onTap: () async {
   if (person.photoUri.isNotEmpty)
      await OpenFile.open(person.photoUri);
},
```